# How can you do a Vlookup on Excel where it pulls different answers depending of the result found?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I have an Excel file where I am trying to create a quote sample where I can automise making quotes for my Company. I have on one page the quote sample, another page with all the customers details and on a third page all the Bank détails. We have 2 different Banks so I would like to be able to create a Vlookup where it sees if the customer should Pay to one Bank or the other then from that pull up one of the Banks détails or the other

I tried to do a If(VLOOKUP...)='...',"..." but it didn't work

Comment: Please how the IF() you created then we may be able to spot an error, because the logic should work.

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE)=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3)

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE));=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3)

Comment: @SolarMike =IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE));=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3)

Comment: So vlookup() returns a value into the logical_test of the if() statement. how is that value used?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Based on the formula you posted, it will not return the correct value correctly (syntax error). Please check how [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2#:~:text=The%20IF%20function%20is%20one,if%20your%20comparison%20is%20False.) works. You may also add more context to your question by illustrating your problem through examples.

Comment: `=IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE) = YOURCHECKINGVALUE; BNP(Data!D2); BPI(Data!D3))` Should work with YOURCHECKINGVALUE the value that you'd expect and want to return the value of your UDF BNP for.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what you need to check based on the last if() you posted:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE);=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3))
```

But the vlookup() gives a value, NOW you need to test it:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE)<test_value;=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3)
```

Or

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE)>test_value;=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3))
```

Or even as a text result:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G3;'Service Entry'!A2:L7;12;FALSE)="text";=BNP(Data!D2);=BPI(Data!D3))
```